Is there a method for a running Flink app get back pressure status?
In the Java code for a Flink app, is there a way to tell if the app is currently experiencing back pressure?  Flink produces back pressure metrics that we can monitor from outside the app, but I'm not currently finding anything in the Java API that would allow the application itself to know if it were experiencing back pressure.
The reason I would like this is that we have an Apache Flink Java app with a dynamic rate limiter built into it.  The rate limiter is built on a token bucket with an elastic capacity.  If the app is using all the tokens, the token bucket can get bigger over time. If the app isn't using the tokens, the token bucket shrinks.  This allows application to handle increases in workload but without sudden spikes in processing rate. That is important in our context because some downstream applications have elastic capacity but need time to allocate more resources as their load increases. They crash if they get huge spikes in output from our application.
The code for calling the rate limit is implemented like:
// Rate limiting, block until a token is available.
var tokenBucket = ThreadLocalsManager.getTokenBucket(
    bucketConfig,
    getRuntimeContext().getNumberOfParallelSubtasks()
);
long waitTimeMs = tokenBucket.blockUntilToken();

The blockUntilToken method causes back pressure in the Flink app that prevents it from working faster than allowed by the token bucket. There is one token bucket per parallelism.  Passing the number of parallel subtasks to it allows it to know what share of the overall work of the app can be handled by this particular bucket. Overall this works very well.
However, if the application experiences back pressure for some reason other than the rate limit, it won't use all the tokens available to it. This causes the token bucket to shrink even though the app is getting behind and building up a backlog. If the back pressure status were available through the Flink Java API, I could use that to prevent the token bucket from shrinking in such situations.

Is there an option to call the Flink REST API to get back pressure information?

If it is only available through a rest API, I'd have to call it far less frequently than for every record processed.  That can be 15,000 per second in this app. An answer with details about how to get it from a REST API would still be useful.
